# Netlogo: is nobody still being treated as an agent?

Tags: netlogo

I have a list of parcel agents. but I will kill the parcels periodically. However, the list is still recording someting like this: [nobody nobody nobody nobody nobody nobody nobody nobody], and overtime the running of the model is getting slower and eventually pop up message "your model is too large to run with available memory"

In this case, are the dead agents (i.e. nobody) still treated as an agents that consumes much of the memory? what if it is a pure list of numbers or strings? would it cause the same OOM issue? how big the list can be in Netlogo and any uppper limit?

Comment: you need to show us the code that kills the parcels. It sounds like you are doing something like `ask turtle [die]` without also using `remove-item` from the list

Comment: YES，one-of my programmer did not do that, which then can be referred to my original question. What is the answer to it?

Comment: you need to show us the code about killing turtles if you want a code answer. Otherwise, as I already said, use the `remove-item` primitive

Comment: ask parcels with [finish? = true] [ die ] --- this is executed in every 120 ticks. ask parcels [die]  --- this is executed at the end of total run-time length of a complete simulation run (2880 ticks)  before next new cycle start. I normally will remove the agent from any list before killing them. But this time someone else did not do that and it cause such as problem. I just want to know how list 
 and dead agent operates under such condition.

Comment: If you're using a list, it should be because your parcels need to be ordered in a specific way. In which case, you can go with Jen's suggestion of using `remove-item` or do something like `set my-list filter is-parcel? my-list`. However, if you **do not** need an ordered list, I would suggest storing your parcels in an agentset instead of list. That would sidestep the problem entirely, as dead agents are automatically removed from agentsets. You would also get slightly nicer syntax for operations involving those parcels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From, the NetLogo dictionary for `die`: If you have a list of agents and the agent dies, then the agent is removed from any agentset and:

- The agent will disappear from any agentsets it was in, reducing the size of those agentsets by one.
- Any variable that was storing the agent will now instead have nobody in it

The dead agents are not consuming resources, but the list is (as you have found by printing out the list). You can see this with the following model:

```
globals [mylist myagentset]

to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 1
  set mylist sort-on [who] turtles
  set myagentset turtles
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  create-turtles 1
  [ set myagentset (turtle-set myagentset self)
  ]
  set mylist lput one-of turtles mylist
  ask one-of turtles [die]
  type "turtles: " print count turtles
  type "list: " print length mylist
  type "agentset: " print count myagentset
  tick
end
```

If you want the dead turtle to be removed from the list, you need to explicitly do so with `remove-item`. The same is true of lists of numbers, strings etc.

Alternatively, if the list doesn't need to be maintained over ticks, but can be reconstructed (eg if it is a sorted list of the turtles agentset), you could create it each tick and that list would only contain turtles that are alive.